# Passing arguments to method pd.read_sql from class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a database interface class that returns queries from pandas `pd.read_sql` function. I would like to pass `pd.read_sql` arguments to the method so that it can be used when the function is called, like below:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


class Database:

    def __init__():
        driver_path = 'blablabla'

    def select(self, query, **kwargs):

        con = pyodbc.connect(driver_path)
        result = pd.read_sql(query, con, kwargs)
        con.close()

        return result
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a way for me to pass arguments to a funcion inside a method like I would with R's ellipsis? (`...`)

For example, I would like to run a query like this:

```
query = "Select * from Table Where Group = '?'"

Database.select(query, params='GROUP1')
```

Comment: Use `pd.read_sql(query, con, params=kwargs)` to [pass parameters to the query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas-read-sql).

Comment: But what if I want to use another parameter, @unutbu? What if in another query I don't want to use params, and want to use *columns* ?

Comment: Thank you, @AkshayNevrekar! You can send it as anwers for me to mark it as correct if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `**` before `kwargs` just the same way you passed it in `select` method:

```
class Database:

    def __init__():
        driver_path = 'blablabla'

    def select(self, query, **kwargs):

        con = pyodbc.connect(driver_path)
        result = pd.read_sql(query, con, **kwargs)
        con.close()

        return result
```